# php form action with recaptcha check

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

Working on a simple contact form, and I'm trying to integrate Google ReCaptcha to eliminate the spam I started receiving.

Right now it's checking to see if the ReCaptcha is successful. If it's not, it just currently reloads the page and resets the form. If it is, I'd like it to fire the receiving contact form php page and pass the form values along with it.

It's getting hung up on that part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

// grab ReCaptcha library
require_once "recaptchalib.php";

// your secret key
$secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

// empty response
$response = null;

// check secret key
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

// if submitted check response
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/form-basic.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="main-content">

    <?php
        $action = '';
        if ($response != null && $response->success) {
            $action = "contactengine.php";
        } else {
    ?>

    <form class="form-basic" action="<?php echo $action ?>" method="post">

        <div class="form-title-row">
            <h1>Get in Touch</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="fdgafafdadfgsdfgrafgaRlifgsfgserysrtyc3H"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Send</button>
        </div>

    </form>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're not posting to the same page, as Midas points out. All the code above DOCTYPE needs to be moved to contactengine.php as that is where you're posting the recaptcha attempt to

Answer (score 0):

You can either move the captcha checking code into the receiving contact form page, or add the contact form processing logic in the main page. You probably want to use the last approach.

Comment: While accurate, you should elaborate a little bit more though, upping this felt like a crime.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll give it shot and report back.